# Enabling the std feature on environmental crate

Tags: evm, frontier, cargo, ethereum

I'm trying to use the environmental crate (link: https://docs.rs/environmental/1.1.3/src/environmental/lib.rs.html#64) to work with EVM and ethereum transactions. But it seems like adding either features=["std"] or environmental/std does'nt work :/

```yaml
[dependencies]
environmental = { version = "1.1.3", features=["std"] }
```

Link:
https://github.com/edgeware-network/edgeware-node/blob/erup-5-latest/primitives/rpc/evm-tracing-events/Cargo.toml#L11

tracelog:

```rust
     Compiling evm-tracing-events v0.1.0 (/home/runner/work/edgeware-node/edgeware-node/primitives/rpc/evm-tracing-events)
  error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope
    --> /home/runner/work/edgeware-node/edgeware-node/primitives/rpc/evm-tracing-events/src/lib.rs:51:1
     |
  51 | environmental::environmental!(listener: dyn Listener + 'static);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `thread_local` is in scope, but it is an attribute: `#[thread_local]`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::thread_local_impl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0425]: cannot find value `GLOBAL` in this scope
    --> /home/runner/work/edgeware-node/edgeware-node/primitives/rpc/evm-tracing-events/src/lib.rs:51:1
     |
  51 | environmental::environmental!(listener: dyn Listener + 'static);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
  error: could not compile `evm-tracing-events` due to 3 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: Process completed with exit code 101.
```

It complains due to missing code parts that needs a feature flag to be added.

Links:
https://docs.rs/environmental/1.1.3/src/environmental/lib.rs.html#66
https://github.com/edgeware-network/edgeware-node/runs/6208406289?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:1538

Does anyone know how I can enable the std features?

Code for pallet:
https://docs.rs/environmental/1.1.3/src/environmental/lib.rs.html#64

Answer (score -1):

non answer: this was because #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)] was enabled on the pallet..

Comment: you _cannot_ use std in your runtime. If you are building a pallet this isn't going to work.

Comment: yeah I realized this... There is some std leak somewhere

Comment: You can also get here if you're accidentally referencing two versions of substrate at the same time.